# The process appear again automatically after I killed it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, kill, inittab

I try to kill a process with `sudo kill 30602`. But after I killed it I use `ps aux | grep gmond` to check, it appear again with another pid.That's like:

```
ganglia  30997  0.0  0.1 121812  2128 ?        Ssl  16:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/gmond --pid-file=/var/run/ganglia-monitor.pid
```

Whatever how I kill it, it just appear again with another pid, even with `kill -9`.

What's the problem? And how to solve this?

Comment: It might be restarted automatically, see [here](http://superuser.com/a/507835/83249).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill respawned process by init in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016641/how-to-kill-respawned-process-by-init-in-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the entry in the `/etc/inittab` file. Probably your `gmond` service entry is starting with `respawn`. It will respawn every time you kill the process.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016641/how-to-kill-respawned-process-by-init-in-linux): To disable the process you have to edit `/etc/inittab` and comment out that line. To inform `init` about this change you have to send a `SIGHUP` to `init`:

`kill -HUP pid-of-init`

The `/etc/inittab` file was the configuration file used by the original System V `init` daemon. The Upstart `init` daemon does not use this file, and instead reads its configuration from files in `/etc/init` directory.

Comment: But I don't have the file..

Comment: And when I run `ps aux | grep init`, I just get `root         1  0.0  0.2  36552  5804 ?        Ss   Jul28   0:02 /sbin/init`

Comment: @Tony In such case `cd /etc/init` then execute `grep -nr "gmond" *"`. It will give the filename containing the entry.